# How to change current fragment in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to change current shown fragment in ViewPager. For example I have 2 type of fragments(FragmentA and FragmentB). Let's say every fragment contain different players, every player can play some format. When user open app he sees FragmentA. If FragmentA can play current format, it will play. If it's not, it will say to ViewPager "Bro I need help". In this way ViewPager has to change FragmentA to FragmentB.
I did it in this way

```
  FragmentB fragment = new FragmentB();
  fragment.setArguments(getArguments());//get arguments from old fragment
  fl.setId(R.id.change_fl);//change id because if I don't change it, 
  //fragment will be set up in first found view with this Id. 
  //Because left and right fragment have the same id, fragmentmanager can set fragment at left  or right side. 
  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.change_fl, fragment)
                .commit();
```

But now I have other problem. When FragmentA changes itself to FragmentB and I scroll to right/left and there's FragmentA try to change itself to FragmentB, fragment will change where fragment was changed before, because its root view has id = R.id.change_fl).
My question is how to replace current(shown) fragment in ViewPager?

Comment: You can use only one fragment to display whatever you want to play in viewpager using FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: @SarithaG In this way user will see the same video twice.

Comment: You should change the video file by sliding the view pager.

Comment: @SarithaG yes, it's mean if user start sliding I have to stop current video thread. But if user just slides a bit but doesn't change fragment, in this way player will start current thread one more time. Also I have different preview on different fragment

Comment: If you are using one video player, using single fragment is the best option, that will automatically stops the playing video and will move to next video when you slide the viewpager.